# nuxtjs - setting background-url to image from assets doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

after lots of research I haven't found a solution which explains why this is happening.

When trying to set the `background-image` in my div dynamically it doesn't work and I am getting an 404 error. `http://localhost:3000/~assets/images/postPreview.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

```
<div
    class="post-thumbnail"
    :style="{backgroundImage: 'url(' + thumbnail + ')'}"></div>
     <div class="post-content">
          <h1> {{ title }}</h1>
          <p> {{ previewText }}</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

I am passing it like this (thumbnail): `~assets/images/postPreview.jpg` and get the above error.

If i pass it like this then it works: `_nuxt/assets/images/postPreview.jpg`

I have tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436017/nuxt-js-how-to-set-css-background-image-dynamicaly) as well but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me out understand what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images should be placed inside static folder then use them like

```
:style="{backgroundImage: 'url(' + thumbnail + ')'}"></div>
```

in your data object :

```
thumbnail :this.$router.options.base+'images/postPreview.jpg'
```